# Wordpress Rest API how to post content with Python

Tags: python, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to post content through the WordPress rest API with my Python script. The issue I am facing however is that when I do my post request I receive in response in JSON format all the posts already existing in the web site instead of it creating a new post. Could someone please support here? My code looks like following:

```
import requests import json import base64

url = "https://myurl.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts" 
user = "Username" 
password = "application password" 
credentials = user + ':' + password 
token = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode()) 
header = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8')} 
post = {  'title'    : 'Test WP-API',   
          'content'  : 'This is my first post created using restAPI',  
          'status'   : 'publish', 
} 
responce = requests.post(url , headers=header, json=post)

print(responce.json())
```

---

I have tried to Google this issue anywhere but just can't seem anyone to having this issue. I would appreciate it so much if someone could support.

Comment: have you double-checked that the new post hasn't been created? perhaps in the web UI or by doing a `GET` call afterwards?

Comment: Yes I am 100% positive because when i look at the web UI i have no posts with that title etc. What I cannot figure out is why i receive all the posts in json format back as response even though i am doing a post request. @ZevAverbach

Comment: believe it or not I actually spun up a free WP site (https://myxomycete-principa.000webhostapp.com/ will remove soon), and was able to use your code to successfully create a post! I can't replicate your issue. For completeness, the WP version is 6.1.1. Here's the JSON response: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/zevaverbach/0f3668cd2e3f42c6d2f152b97471461e/raw/55c8215e1d9e3b8fa3940d2709a4470279c19b9e/gistfile1.txt

Comment: Ok, so I am wondering then what it is you're typing in the "url" section. I believe this is where I mess up and it does not become correct. Is there someway to find what my url is? Since I am using a theme called RE:Hub I am starting to think i dont insert the correct URL.

Comment: sure, the URL is "https://myxomycete-principa.000webhostapp.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"

Comment: This is exactly what I also type in for my website. What i receive however is the whole json format as you would be entering into the url you provided. It is like my "POST" acts like a "GET" I feel very confused lol. You have any ideas how or why this could be happening?

Comment: I can also add an additional comment here which is that if I do not enter the username and application password I receive the same response as if I would type it in. I just receive the whole websites content in JSON-format.

Comment: That's unexpected! I can report that I instead get a 401 response.

Comment: Yes, I also receive an [200] response always no matter if i have correct credentials or not and I also receive the whole websites frontpage in json-format from the print I am doing even though i do requests.post and not a requests.get. Do you have any idea how I can tackle this? I have no clue about how to proceed neither from where to start the investigation.

Comment: this is super-obscure. can you post ALL of your code? I'm wondering if something is getting unexpectedly mutated (like `requests` functions).

Comment: This is all the code I am using... @ZevAverbach

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same problem. As far as I can remember I solved it with setting the author (integer index!) and providing a slug. (Not sure if you can publish though. IMHO status should be 'published' then, not 'publish')

```
data = {
        'title': 'Test WP API',
        'status': 'draft',
        'slug': 'test-wp-api',
        'author': 1,
        'content': 'This is my first post created using REST-API'
    }
```